# Padding for all device in flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I want to give padding for all mobile device. I give a padding. But that works for only device on that I have tested. If I use different device then that is not working. I used like this:

```
padding: EdgeInsets.only() and 
padding: EdgeInsets.all()
```

this two function I have used. 
Is there a way to make responsive? If I give padding then that will work for every device like percentage in CSS.

it's not fitting to screen. 
[image]

but in small screen it's fitting!

Comment: Can you add screenshots off your devices in which you tested ?

Comment: I added. it's not fitting to this screen. But in smaller screen it's fitting

Answer (score 1):

You can use widgets such as `Align` for percentage padding using `heightFactor` and `widthFactor`:

```
Align(
  heightFactor: .30,
  widthFactor: .30,
  child: child,
)
```

This will make the make the `Align` 30% bigger than its child. And align its child within that space.

You can play around `align` property to achieve different behaviors.

Comment: Yeah, although that one is more for percentage width/height.

Comment: your answer is 30% way through. i think percentage padding is far from ok

Answer (score 1):

MediaQuery.of(context).size.width And MediaQuery.of(context).size.height allow you to find out the width and height of the device so that you can provide padding in percentage of that width and height so that you can maintain the ratio in every device.